# Questions about technical aspects of Gödel's proof of his Completeness Theorem

Tags: logic

I'm trying to refresh my knowledge about mathematical logic and I'm still unsatisfied with my insight of Gödel's Completeness Theorem.

I have read Gödel's original paper (1930 - reprinted into **J.van Heijenoort** (editor), *From Frege to Gödel*, 1967) but I'm still unsatisfied with my understanding of it. I've tried also with Wikipedia's entry about [Gödel's proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Original_proof_of_G%C3%B6del%27s_completeness_theorem) but I'm still struggling with it.

I've also tried with some "modern translations" : **J.L.Bell & A.B.Slomson**, *Models and Ultraproducts* (1969), Ch.12.1: **Gödel's completeness proof** (pag.233-on) and with **S.C.Kleene**, *Introduction to Metamathematics* (1952), para.72 : **Gödel's completeness theorem** (pag.389-on), without a good mastering of the details.

So this are my first question :

> Are there available detailed comments/explanations of Gödel's original proof, with all the needed details explicitely supplied ?

I've studied Henkin's version and I think I've mastered it. Some textbooks (e.g.**Ian Chiswell & Wilfrid Hodges**, *Mathematical Logic* (2007), introduce Henkin's construction with sentential logic, I think in order to "introduce" the student to the construction "testing" it in a simplified environment. My second question is :

> Make it sense trying to adapt Gödel's original proof to sentential calculus in order to understand the specific details necessary to prove it for f-o logic ?

Comment: Try to find a copy of Elliott Mendelson's Introduction to Mathematical Logic in your closest library. The first two chapters cover what you want.

Comment: The proof goes differently than what Godel did,but the way it is done gives a deeper understanding.